# Some of my search results don't have datums in local storage

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have been trying to research this for a while and I have found one person with a similar problem but there was no solution to his question:

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1340

Some of my bloodhound objects are producing expected results into local storage however two of them are missing the **data** (datums). Even though they are missing the datum part everything else works. I can search with type-ahead as expected. I would like to know why these two objects don't have the data stored.

I now try to use cacheKey attribute instead of the default so this image does not show me using the cacheKey attribute.

### [Sample Image : Local Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLV1X.png)

Here is a part of my code that uses typeahead. The typeahead works but it's not being stored in local storage:

## JavaScript:

```
var sections = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        $(".loadingSections").hide();
        var namepartTokens = Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword(d);
        var nameTokens = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d);
        var allTokens = namepartTokens.concat(nameTokens);

        return allTokens;
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: classLookUp,
        cacheKey: 'sectionLookUp'
    }
});

sections.initialize();

$(".section-lookup .typeahead").typeahead({ highlight: true }, {
    source: sections.ttAdapter()
});
```

## HTML

```
...
<script>
    var classLookUp = '@Url.Action("GetClassNames", "Home")';
    ...
</script>
...
 <div class="form-group section-lookup">
     <div class="loadingSections"></div>
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Section:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control typeahead", @id = "editLookup", @placeholder = "ex. 15/FA CIS-131-102" })
     </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="editSearch" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">Search for Course</button>
```

## C#

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult GetClassNames()
 {
     try
     {
         var newSections = this.repo.Courses;
         var names = newSections.Select(course => course.DisplayName).ToList();
         return this.Json(names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     catch (DatabaseConnectionException)
     {
         return this.Json(new { failure = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
 }
```

Note: I seem to be far away from exceeding localstorage max storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why it's not being stored in local storage. The reason is exceeding local storage max storage. I found out at the end of the datum section being stored there is a trie attribute that it stores along with it. Even if your list has only 3,000 elements the trie attached with it is massive enough to take a lot of storage space. So there was unknown overhead.

trie: It seems to be the tree for searching. I would like a way to store only the datum section and have the tree always generated client side. This way we can have more things stored on local storage. Not having this as a default defeats the purpose of prefech which the idea was to not having calls to the server. I know the tree is being build client side but we do not need to have it saved in local storage.